# Не работает reportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

При попытке перетаскивания reportviewer на форму из панели элементов выходит следующая ошибка, ума не приложу что с ней делать. Прикладываю скриншот ошибки и установленные пакеты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В процессе установки где-то накосячили:) переустановите и проверьте

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato
переустанавливал компоненты Nuget, расширение report viewer и даже сам vs. Ничего не помогает(